# Antonym of 'stigma'

Tags: meaning, word-choice, antonyms

I am looking for a word that has the opposite, positive connotation from 'stigma':

For example,

> There is a stigma of laziness associated with poor people.

What would be the replacement for 'stigma' in this sentence in opposite world:

> There is a ??? of industriousness associated with rich people.

Using a thesaurus tends towards cleanliness or lack of blemish. But I'm thinking of 'stigma' not as a blemish, but rather a negative connotation, so that the antonym I'm looking for is not the lack of a blemish but a postive connotation (i.e. that 'stigma' -means- 'negative connotation').

Comment: Specifically, an unjustified positive connotation?

Comment: @Sam: Sorry, yes, I was trying to keep as simple as possible, but that makes my example sentences pretty inflammatory. 'Unjustifiable' and 'mythical' are things I would apply to both situations (which actually is my main motivation. I keep sensing in others that rich people have an (I find) extremely unfounded aura of 'betterness' attached to them...um...did I just answer my own question?)

Comment: How about instead of _extremely unfounded_ which does seem prejudicial, something like, a _possibly undeserved_ aura?

Comment: Notwithstanding the specific example in OP, is it to be generally supposed that a 'stigma' is *unjustified*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: as part of the connotations of the words, no, there is no sense of justified or unjustified at all, just that there is some kind of special psychological ...'thing' about the modified object, such as your adversaries in a game are seen to be 'evil', or when a team loses a game, they feel like they are somehow 'bad'. None of these are necessary at all, just commonly associated. I am calling these stigmas, and I'm looking for a positive version.

Comment: I agree with the voters (and myself?): 'aura' is the best sounding 'antonym' despite halo being more logically opposite. 'reputation' and 'air' are both good, but you have to add 'good' or 'bad' to complete them (they are neutral in direction). And 'patina' could work in the right context, too.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Aura* might work, as it has a generally positive connotation. There is also *halo*, though that might be a little over-the-top in this case, or the more neutral *property*.

Comment: 'Aura' is the direction I'm looking for...it doesn't pop out as the totally obvious selection to me (yet).

Comment: +1 for aura. A similar word would be _air_: They have an air of industriousness about them.

Comment: Definitely aura, as they both have theological connotations.

Answer (score 9):

Here are a few options:

- virtue
- principle
- reputation
- character
- acclaim
- plaudits

Most of these were gleaned from a thesaurus entry for *honor*.

Comment: 'virtue' or 'honor' might work. They're not what I expected, but both have easy antonyms with connotations that might work in given context.

Comment: 'reputation' might work  well both negatively and positively.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider the word "patina" as an option.

Comment: or 'veneer' too but those have the extra connotation of covering up, cosmetic appearance, which can be considered slightly negative. I'm looking for something that is just plain positive.

Comment: Also consider "air," as in, "She had an air of success about her." Still, "patina" would be my choice as it is almost always used in a positive sense, alluding to qualities burnished over time.

Comment: 'air' sounds more neutral but might work for both positive and negative. You're convincing me little by little that 'patina' might work too. Annoyingly, online definitions give hardly any nuance to any of these, even the well-known metaphorical use of 'patina'.

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of "mark of distinction", "status symbol", "noble bearing" seems to have the connotations you are asking for, but they don't fit your example sentence.

Do any of these sentences have the connotations you are searching for?

- There is a quality of industriousness associated with rich people.
- There is a continuing motion of industriousness ...
- There is an outpouring of industriousness ...
- There is a badge of industriousness ...
- There is a mark of industriousness ...
- There is a stamp of industriousness ...
- There is a distinctive mark of industriousness ...
- There is a distinctive stamp of industriousness ...
- There is the presence of industriousness ...
- There is the attribute of industriousness ...
- There is an appearance of industriousness ...
- There is an implied subtext of industriousness ...
- There is an expectation of industriousness ...
- There is an assumption of industriousness ...
- There is an abundance of industriousness ...
- There is a stereotype of industriousness ...

Comment: 'mark','stamp':close to the implication of stigma of something preent on the surface.'attribute','subtext','stereotype' in the sense of connotation or associated features.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest "air".

From Thesaurus.com:

> Main Entry:   air
>
> Part of Speech:   noun
>
> Definition:   distinctive quality or character; style

Answer (score 2):

I think "prestige" would be the word, but you would have to re-work the sentence.

A drop-in fit would be "aura" or "halo".

Answer (score 1):

If OP *is* looking for an antonym that includes some negative connotations, I suggest *kudos*.

In my experience *kudos* is often used somewhat disparagingly, with a suggestion that the reputation being refered to may in fact be undeserved or overrated.

In light of subsequent clarification from OP, I suggest *hallmark*. It can't be used in exactly the same way as some other offerings, and sometimes it's used in reference to *undesirable* qualities, but "The hallmark of industriousness is associated with rich people" sounds good to me.

Comment: For what ever reason, I've never found 'kudos' to have good 'mouth-feel'. It also has the connotation of the action of congratulations (what's the opposite of that?), whereas 'stigma' is just a static thing.

Comment: If we can discard the requirement that our two words should have either positive or negative connotations, I'd go for *stamp* as being pretty neutral in either example.

Comment: *kudos* isn't quite the right part of speech, though. Or something. Anyway, it doesn't work in "There is a ??? of industriousness associated with rich people."

Comment: @Martha: I agree *There is a kudos of industiousness associated with rich people* sounds a bit 'iffy'. But *The kudos of industriousness is associated...* seems perfectly unremarkable to me.

Answer (score 1):

honor/respect/pride/aura/halo/appreciation

Answer (score 0):

the *glow of* x? The *patina of* y? *Luminousity* of z?