# Word or phrase indicating incompetence or unsuitability?

Tags: nouns

This may be as simple as a synonym for *hallmark*, but with a negative connotation.

An example:
A security consultant publishes an article on security practices that is so egregiously erroneous that it reflects poorly on 3rd parties who cite the article or author. The poor reflection is what I'm trying to describe.

*Black mark* is close, but I'd like to find a word taking a stronger stance - one could have multiple black marks that are overcome by strong qualities, while *this word/phrase* is effectively the end of the discussion.

Maybe *deal breaker*, but less vernacular.

Comment: Why not just say it's *egregiously erroneous*?

Comment: I must say I like the idea of a hallmark for incompetence. _Microsoft Certified Stupid Engineer_, perhaps?

Comment: Despite the fact that you've accepted a good answer among many, I still find it unclear what you want. A 'black mark'/'stigma'/'stain' is not the "end of a discussion", but a 'deal breaker' is. Is it a vague association of negativity that you want or a no go/show stopper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word you may be looking for is *[stigma](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stigma)*:

> **stigma**, *noun*
>
> : An association of disgrace or public disapproval with something,
>   such as an action or condition [AHED]
>
> : a mark of shame or discredit [MW]

Comment: See this ELU question for going from the opposite direction [starting from stigma](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18943/antonym-of-stigma).

Comment: @Mitch Interesting; the mark of Cain vs a halo for the opposite.

Comment: '...cast a pall over' or 'a dark cloud over' or 'a stain on' are phrases that seem to fit here, too.

Comment: @Mitch Ah; I was so locked into "a word" that I overlooked phrases entirely.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with **discredited** as an adjective, **discredit** as verb or noun. [From TheFreeDictionaryOneline](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discredited):

> **dis·cred·it**
>   *tr.v.* dis·cred·it·ed, dis·cred·it·ing, dis·cred·its
>   1. To damage in reputation; disgrace.
>   2. To cause to be doubted or distrusted.
>   3. To refuse to believe.
>   *n.*
>   1. Loss of or damage to one's reputation.
>   2. Lack or loss of trust or belief; doubt.
>   3. Something damaging to one's reputation or stature.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "fatal flaw?".  Indead, you can put "fatal" before many constructions in order to turn them into deal breakers.  So "fatal black mark" works, and as a bonus, it reminds people of Treasure Island.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the words **"inadequate"** , **"inefficient"** or the phrase **"lions led by donkeys"** meaning leading to loss because of incompetent and indifferent leaders.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, but I am going to have to start using "lions led by donkeys."

Comment: @harlanlewis I think the phrase "the blind leading the blind" is better understood.

Comment: Half the fun is how unexpected it is :)

Answer (score 2):

**Disreputable** may be close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

*[Kiss of death](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kiss+of+death)*, "Something that is ultimately ruinous, destructive, or fatal" is a possibility.

One might also refer to the original article as *[toxic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toxic)*.  The word means, literally, "Having a chemical nature that is harmful to health or lethal if consumed..." but used figuratively could suggest an article is lethal when quoted.  Note, [synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/acliq?r=12011708_1326784195_457981707) of *lethal* such as *deadly* and *fatal* might also apply.

Comment: I like the word "toxic" -- the phrase "toxic assets" became popular after 2008 to describe real estate securities that nobody wanted on their books, and anyone familar with that phrase would find it appropriate for a reference that nobody wants to mention.

Comment: Toxic is definitely appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

***atrocious***
The word also has a commonly used sense of 'full of errors'.

adjective /əˈtrōSHəs/ 
Of a very poor quality; extremely bad or unpleasant
- *he attempted an atrocious imitation of my English accent*
informal : *atrocious spelling*, *atrocious writing*, *atrocious driving*

In typical cases as in your context, usually the diplomatic way to say something is too erroneous is to call it ***specious***.

[**spe·cious**](http://www.memrise.com/item/736628/specious-adj-misleading-in-appearance-esp-misleadi/) /ˈspēSHəs/
*Adjective*:
Superficially plausible, but actually wrong: "a specious argument".
Misleading in appearance, esp. misleadingly attractive: "a specious appearance of novelty".