# Looking for the antonym of stigmatizing

Tags: antonyms

What is the antonym for "stigmatizing"?

I would like to describe this idea that people will stigmatize or [???] someone based on his conduct. Like saying that he is dishonorable [stigma] or a man of honor [???].

I feel *admiring* cannot express what I mean.

Comment: _Stigmatize_ is a very strong word. Are you sure it's the one you want?

Comment: There are [pages of synonyms (and on each antonym) of 'stigmatize'](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/stigmatize?s=t) [pages of synonyms of words like 'exalt'](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exalt?s=t). What exactly do you want about stigmatize? Is it demonization? Is it disrespect or dishonor?

Comment: See also [Antonym of 'stigma'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18943/antonym-of-stigma)

Comment: Are you looking for an adjective or a verb to describe a person's conduct>

Comment: First time I've seen _stigmatize_ used as a verb rather than an adjective. You learn something new every day.

Comment: It sounds like shameful or disgraceful are antonyms of the accepted answer, rather than stigmatizing. Is that what you meant instead of stigmatizing? If you're stigmatized, there tends to be a specific reason for it, is what I mean (like you're stigmatized because you have naturally violet hair and everyone thinks that means you're poor). It's not just a general state of being without regard to specifics, although you could use it generally in some ways, like if you're talking about multiple kinds of stigma and aren't specifying what they are, maybe.

Comment: I would suggest "whitewash".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's an antonym of demonize (other than deify)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302328/whats-an-antonym-of-demonize-other-than-deify)

Comment: @Mari-LouA demonize and stigmatize aren't synonyms, are they? They haven't the same exact meaning.

Comment: The request is the same though :) Just look at the answers...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about **[praise](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/praise)**?

According to Oxford Dictionaries

> Express warm approval or admiration of.

**sing the praises of**

> Express enthusiastic approval or admiration of.

---

Also, you can search in a Thesaurus and choose the one you like most
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/stigma

I want to congratulate Dávid Leblay for his suggestion **glorify**, because I think that it preserves the touch of religiosity that stigmatize transmits.

Looking for the exact meaning of **apotheosize** (suggested by @Fattie), I've found another good one

> [**idolize**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idolize)
>
> Admire, revere, or love greatly or excessively.

Comment: While admirable, this is not really correct, I don't think.  Glorify is better.

Comment: @Fattie I agree with you but my answer is not too bad taking in account that "glorify" is a synonym of "praise" https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/glorify And that glorify is: to praise and honour God or a person https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glorify

Comment: @Mari-LouA I already knew about the edit history, I've been around almost the same time than you in Stack Exchange but I wanted to remark the change. I've seen references to other persons' answers in this site, I didn't know that it was something to avoid. I think that there is too much edition/moderation in these English Language sites sometimes for no reason.

Comment: I think it's confusing to have three, four different answers on the same post.  Doubly so when the answers are by different users. So which answer did the OP accept and saw most fitting? Lebay's, perhaps fattie's (which you said inspired "idolize")  or your own two solutions?

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's why I wrote [EDITED]. But what's the problem in not knowing which one picked OP? My word is not the best, the community have chosen "lionize". For those that will come in the future, that probably will read only the accepted answer and the most valued, I'm hightlighting that there are other remarkable words and I'm crediting who suggested them.

Answer (score 31):

You could use **lionise** / **lionize**.

> *lionize*: give a lot of public attention and approval to (someone); treat as a celebrity.
>
> *modern sportsmen are lionized and feted*
>
> *Nevertheless, he is a flamboyant showman, fond of electric blue suits, who once turned up on a motorbike to wild applause at the
>   Cannes festival, where he is lionised.*
>
> *People will lionize you as the Voice of a Generation.*
>
> *In 1778, after an absence of 28 years, he made a triumphal return to Paris, where he was lionized for four months in a way few writers can
>   ever have experienced.*

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lionize)]

Comment: Excellent. I'm reminded of the reaction to Mamoudou Gassama and his magnificent scaling of the Paris building to rescue the child. Gassama has been rightly 'lionized' for his heroic act.

Comment: One wonders whether people scaling Nelson's Column might be lionised.

Comment: (And that's probably the only time I've ever said that on this site  :)   :)  )

Comment: Nice word! Its [paywalled OED entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/108816).

Answer (score 10):

I think glorify works the best, as it is pretty casual, but quite descriptive. Or, depending on context, idolize might be the one you're looking for.

If you want something a bit more fancy, I think [exalt](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/exalt), and its synonyms are excellent

Comment: Glorify is a good suggestion and it preserves some touch of religiosity that always suggest stigmatize.

Answer (score 5):

Antonyms include [*valorize*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/valorize) (in American English) or *valorise* (in British English), *exalt*, *extol* and *acclaim* (all transitive verbs), or *pay homage* (intransitive, but can take *to* and an indirect object).

I think these are particularly close antonyms because they all mean attempting to raise someone’s reputation, but *valorize* is the closest because the subject of the verb does not have to be a person and it does not imply a speech-act.

Take, for example, the sentence, “Memorial Day *valorizes* America’s fallen troops.”  That’s the closest antonym I can think of to a phrase like “stigmatizes Vietnam veterans.”  The word *exalt* would also work, but doesn’t sound as good to me.  It would be incorrect to say *extol* or *praise*, because those are things only a person can do.  We can *stigmatize* through our actions or by implication, but *acclaim* or *praise* is more specifically a speech-act.  We could also say *honor* or *pay respect to* in this context, but those are broader: they could also be things we do in private, and *stigmatize* necessarily means damaging someone’s public reputation.

If we say *glorify* here, that connotes undeserved praise, in much the same way that *stigmatize* connotes undeserved oppobrium, so in one sense it’s a better antonym, and in another, a worse one.  Interestingly, *honor* is the only one of those words that specifically implies the person receiving the homage deserves it, but I can think of many others that carry the opposite implication.

Comment: [See the Oxford English Dictionary entry for *valorize*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/221234) [sic].

Comment: @tchrist What part of it do you mean to highlight?

Comment: I found the first citation interesting, the one about valorizing prices: *“It attempted both to regulate the output and to stabilise and to ‘valorise’ the prices.”* The current sense has drifted a bit since that earliest citation from 1921.

Comment: @tchrist I’m unable to read it from here, but the original sense was “raise the value of,” from which I guess it came to mean something like talking your book. Another good one from the OED is where it tells what must have been a current joke among academics in the 1890s: the example for “enormous,” which was then losing its connotation of *abnormally, scandalously* big, was a parvenu businessman boasting of his enormous profits and not knowing how right he was.

Answer (score 3):

Normalizing.

Here's an example of that use: http://freebeacon.com/politics/steyer-not-talking-impeachment-pelosi-normalizing-trump/

Answer (score 2):

Paying homage to. Or still, esteeming.

Answer (score 2):

legitimize

This will vary by context but in some cases is exactly the right word.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use enshrining - to contain or keep something as if in a holy place:

Almost two and a half million war dead are enshrined at Yasukuni.
A lot of memories are enshrined in this photograph album.

Answer (score 1):

Sanctify: "set apart as or declare holy; consecrate."

While this is more accurately an antonym for "demonize", it also works as an antonym for "stigmatize". Stigmatizing something is to make it undesirable/unclean/disfavored to most. Sanctifying something is the process of making it desirable/holy/favored by most.

Answer (score 0):

The word you perhaps want is

## apotheosis.

That's about as strong as it gets!

Comment: Good one, but OP's looking for a verb: apotheosize ;-P

Comment: right on, @RubioRic !

Answer (score 0):

How about **glamorizing**?

Depending on the context, an organisation may wish to forster and encourage certain behaviors it deems positive and constructive, by adding an air of glamour to particular eminent exemplars of same.

For example, a university may allow athletics stars who practice a healthy lifestyle and strong work ethic to have certain privileges and the equivalents of some kinds of [badges of honor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badge_of_honour).